# How to design service that can provide interface as JAX-WS web service, or via JMS, or as local method calls within Java EE framework?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jms

Using a typical Java EE framework, how do I develop and
deploy a service that can be called as a web service
(with a WSDL interface), be invoked via JMS messages,
or called directly from another service in the same
container?

Here's some more context:

Currently I am responsible for a service 
(let's call it Service X) with the following
properties:

- Interface definition is a human readable
  document kept up-to-date manually.
- Accepts HTTP form-encoded requests to a single URL.
- Sends plain old XML responses (no schema).
- Uses Apache to accept requests + a
  proprietary application server (not servlet
  or EJB based) containing all logic which
  runs in a seperate tier.
- Makes heavy use of a relational database.
- Called both by internal applications
  written in a variety of languages and
  also by a small number of third-parties.

I want to (or at least, have been told to!):

- Switch to a well-known (pref. open source) Java EE
  stack such as JBoss, Glassfish, etc.
- Split Service X into Service A and Service B
  so that we can take Service B down for maintenance
  without affecting Service A. Note that Service
  B will depend on (i.e. need to make requests to)
  Service A.
- Make both services easier for third parties to
  integrate with by providing at least a WS-I style
  interface (WSDL + SOAP + XML + HTTP) and probably
  a JMS interface too. In future we might consider
  a more lightweight API too (REST + JSON? Google
  Protocol Buffers?) but that's a nice to have.

Additional consideration are:

- On a smaller deployment, Service A and Service B
  will likely to running on the same machine and it
  would seem rather silly for them to use HTTP or a
  message bus to communicate; better if they could
  run in the same container and make method calls to
  each other.
- Backwards compatibility with the existing ad-hoc
  Service X interface is not required, and we're not
  planning on re-using too much of the existing code
  for the new services.
- I'm happy with either contract-first (WSDL I guess)
  or (annotated) code-first development.

Apologies if my terminology is a bit hazy - I'm
pretty experienced with Java and web programming
in general, but am finding it quite hard to get up
to speed with all this enterprise / SOA stuff - it
seems I have a lot to learn! I'm also not very used
to using a framework rather than simply writing code
that calls some packages to do things.

I've got as far as downloading Glassfish, knocking
up a simple WSDL file and using wsimport + a little
dummy code to turn that into a WAR file which I've
deployed.